# Laravel BroadCast событий в Redis и Listener их от туда

Tags: laravel, события, очередь, redis

Всем привет. У меня сайт размещен на нескольких серверах, при этом общая база REDIS. Balancer распределяет посетителей моего сайта по серверам. Хотел бы разобраться есть ли с коробки решение для трансляции событий в REDIS и что бы на всех серверах LISTENER слушал событие и обрабатывал при получении.

Т.е например пользователь зарегистрировался на сервере 1, создалось событие UserRegister. И по нему у меня должен выполнится код и на сервере 1, и на сервере 2 и т.п.

Можно ли это сделать с коробки, если нет то как можно реализовать?

Comment: Не могу точно утверждать, но вряд ли что-то есть из коробки, потому что Laravel не умеет слушать что-то извне (даже те же сокеты работают только в одну сторону)...

Comment: Использовать брокер сообщений по принципу автор-подписчик, и слушать их постоянно. Создаёте пользователя бросаете меседж в брокер пусть другие сервера самостоятельно разгребают

Answer (score 0):

[@VladimirGonchar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300171/vladimir-gonchar):

Не могу точно утверждать, но вряд ли что-то есть из коробки, потому что Laravel не умеет слушать что-то извне (даже те же сокеты работают только в одну сторону).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Тут согласен, но возможно есть готовые решения в виде пакетов? Ведь в Laravel'е есть Redis::subscribe который по сути будет умеет слушать, на его основе может какой-то пакет?